# Splitting addresses using the space after the postal code with regex Java

Tags: java, regex, split

There are some raw rows with two or more addresses, I want to split them based on the last part of the Canadian postal code using a [look-arround](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) mechanism.
The Canadian postal code format is A1A 1A1, where A is a letter and 1 is a digit, with a space separating the third and fourth characters.

Here is an example

`160 Rue, Notre Dame N, Bureau 140, Sainte-Marie, G6E 3Z9 887 Chemin du Bord de l'Eau, Saint-Henri de Levis, G0R 3E0`

I want to split the address based on the space after the last part of postal code if it exists
The result:

```
160 Rue, Notre Dame N, Bureau 140, Sainte-Marie, G6E 3Z9
887 Chemin du Bord de l'Eau, Saint-Henri de Levis, G0R 3E0
```

I tried

```
List<String>  addresses = new ArrayList<String>();
addresses =  Arrays.asList(long_addresses.Address.split("(\\d\\w\\d)\\s"));
```

But the result is:

> [, Rue, Notre Dame N, Bureau 140, Sainte-Marie, G6E , , Chemin du Bord de l'Eau, Saint-Henri de Levis, G0R 3E0]

Here are some other exanmples

> 141 rang du brûlé, pont rouge, G3H1B8 200 rue Commerciale, Donnacona, G3M 1W1

> 33 rue provost, Montreal, H8S 1L3 46 avenue Sainte-Anne, Pointe-Claire, H9S 4P8 2035 rue Victoria, Lachine, H8S 0A8 2075 rue de l'Eglise, Saint-Laurent, H4M 1G3 800 Pl Leigh-Capreol, Dorval, Montréal, H4Y 0A4

> 2075 rue de l'Eglise, Saint-Laurent, H4M 1G3 2035 rue Victoria, Lachine, H8S 0A8 46 ave, Sainte-Anne, Pointe-Claire, H9S 4P8 12 Charlevoix , Kirkland, H9J 2T6 930 St Germain St, Ville St-Laurent, H4L 3R9 1417 argyle , Montreal, H3G 1V5

Note: I trim the last postal code that does not have a space.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you, it seems it works I am checking other rows to see they work fine or not. Please write it as an answer and explain the regex. I want to accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(?<=\b[a-zA-Z]\d[a-zA-Z]\s\d[a-zA-Z]\d)\s+
```

Or, if the space between the `A1A` and `1A1` is optional, and can go missing, you can use

```
(?<=\b[a-zA-Z]\d[a-zA-Z]\s{0,1}\d[a-zA-Z]\d)\s+
```

This will still work since Java regex engine supports constrained width lookbehind patterns.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JL5TSw/1) / [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/JL5TSw/2). *Details*:

- `(?<=\b[a-zA-Z]\d[a-zA-Z]\s\d[a-zA-Z]\d)` - a positive lookbehind that requires (immediately to the left of the current location):

  - `\b` - a word boundary
  - `[a-zA-Z]` - a letter
  - `\d` - a digit
  - `[a-zA-Z]\s\d[a-zA-Z]\d` - a letter, a whitespace, digit, letter and a digit
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces.

The `\s{0,1}` matches one or zero whitespaces.

See the [Java demo online](https://ideone.com/Khd4EI):

```java
String s = "160 Rue, Notre Dame N, Bureau 140, Sainte-Marie, G6E 3Z9 887 Chemin du Bord de l'Eau, Saint-Henri de Levis, G0R 3E0";
String regex = "(?<=\\b[a-zA-Z]\\d[a-zA-Z]\\s\\d[a-zA-Z]\\d)\\s+";
// Or
// String regex = "(?<=\\b[a-zA-Z]\\d[a-zA-Z]\\s{0,1}\\d[a-zA-Z]\\d)\\s+";
String results[] = s.split(regex);
for (String str: results) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Output:

```
160 Rue, Notre Dame N, Bureau 140, Sainte-Marie, G6E 3Z9
887 Chemin du Bord de l'Eau, Saint-Henri de Levis, G0R 3E0
```